# d3js: Add quantitative dimension to Hierarchical Edge Bundling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Given Mike Bostock's example on Hierarchical Edge Bundling (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999), how would one add a quantitative dimension to the plot?

What I want to achieve is, for example, the link between *"Visualization"* (at 12 o'clock) and *"SpanningTree"* (at 1 o'clock) to have a transparency of 50% and the link between *"Visualization"* and *"AspectRatioBanker"* (also 1 o'clock) to have 0% transparency. Let's assume *"SpanningTree"* is a less important import of *"Visualization"* than *"AspectRatiobanker"* and I want to visualize this aspect using this gradient colour scale.

Considering the data, every element in the `"imports"` array must have a numeric value, indicating the "importance" of that element.

Considering d3, every link has to be coloured based on this numeric value.

Is there a possibility to add such a feature without changing too much of the example code?

Comment: I think this is the wrong kind of question for stack overflow. You dont have a defined problem tried something and cant get it to work, but more an idea of what you'd like to do and looking for someone to do it for you? In the general, if every imports has a numeric value you could base color and opacity on that value. In the actual, thats going to take work and an understanding of whats going on in the example code.
To answer your question, its possible but without changing too much of the code? I dont know, probably not. whats too much? Have you tried changing the example?

Comment: When you say `every link has to be coloured based on this numeric value`, do you mean a color based on value or an opacity based on value or both?

Comment: Never-mind, I got you, you are saying it is currently basing importance using opacity and you'd rather do it on color...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to start with data like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": [
      {
        "link": "flare.animate.Transitioner",
        "value": 47.194114234125514
      },
      {
        "link": "flare.vis.data.DataList",
        "value": 66.57002100495298
      },
      {
        "link": "flare.util.math.IMatrix",
        "value": 5.987508739765435
      },
      {
        "link": "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
        "value": 31.750046370493678
      },
      {
        "link": "flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster",
        "value": 10.186873728884827
      },
      {
        "link": "flare.vis.data.Data",
        "value": 28.60757703865271
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

And then color the links based on the `value` property in the imports.

To do that given the linked example, modify the `packageImports` function to retain the value property in the `links` collection:

```
// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      var target = map[i.link]; // find the target
      target.value = i.value; // retain the value
      imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: target});
    });
  });
  return imports;
}
```

Then add the color when you append the nodes:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
  .range(["#2c7bb6", "#00a6ca","#00ccbc","#90eb9d","#ffff8c","#f9d057","#f29e2e","#e76818","#d7191c"])
  .domain([0,100]);

...

link = link
  .data(bundle(links))
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", line)
  .style("stroke", function(d){
    return colorScale(d.target.value); //<-- add color
  });
```

Full running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node:hover,
.node--source,
.node--target {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.link--source,
.link--target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var diameter = 960,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius])
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.85)
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/851bd2f2-d85d-11e6-b16a-ad927fd57221", function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
      links = packageImports(nodes);
      
  var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(["#2c7bb6", "#00a6ca","#00ccbc","#90eb9d","#ffff8c","#f9d057","#f29e2e","#e76818","#d7191c"])
    .domain([0,100]);

  link = link
      .data(bundle(links))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line)
      .style("stroke", function(d){
        return colorScale(d.target.value);
      })

  node = node
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
      //.on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      //.on("mouseout", mouseouted);
});

/*
function mouseovered(d) {
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

  link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
    .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

  node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);

  node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
}
*/

//d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return map[""];
}

// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      var target = map[i.link];
      target.value = i.value;
      imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: target});
    });
  });
  return imports;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I will accept your answer, because it answers my question generally. I want the colours to appear only `.on(mousover)`, but this seems to be a trivial task I won't need any help with.