# Unexpected token / in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I am using the answer here: [d3js: Add quantitative dimension to Hierarchical Edge Bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441987/d3js-add-quantitative-dimension-to-hierarchical-edge-bundling)
but cannot make it work.

Here is my json file:

```
[
    {
        "name":"flare_MMR_Elektronizace veřejných zakázek",
        "size":1,
        "imports":[
            {
                "link":"flare_NÚKIB_Kybernetická bezpečnost",
                "value":20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"flare_NÚKIB_Kybernetická bezpečnost",
        "size":1,
        "imports":[
            {
                "link":"flare_MMR_Elektronizace veřejných zakázek",
                "value":20
            },
            {
                "link":"flare_MŽP_Zlepšení kvality ovzduší",
                "value":80
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"flare_MŽP_Zlepšení kvality ovzduší",
        "size":1,
        "imports":[
            {
                "link":"flare_NÚKIB_Kybernetická bezpečnost",
                "value":80
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
colorsShouldWorkTemplate.html:73 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 577
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.uo (d3.v3.min.js:3)
    at XMLHttpRequest.i (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

I'm pretty desperate, tried playing around with the json, but with no luck..

Comment: Your JSON looks valid - can you show how you're getting it from a file into the place it's being used?

Comment: That JSON doesn't contain a `/` though, are you sure you're showing us the right file? Character #577 is a `m`.

Comment: you can use [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/) to make sure your json is valid